# need a simple programming logic solution..

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, logic, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x but right now my question has nothing to do with the syntax. I need a solution for this problem:
I have a table named **messages** in which there is a field name **mobile numbers**. The numbers are in this format:

12345678 and +9112345678 .. so they are both the same. The only difference is that in one number the country code is missing.

So I do this query in the database:
select the **distinct** numbers from messages tables..
Now it is taking these both numbers as distinct. But what I want is to take these both numbers as one. 
How can I do this? In my DB there are several numbers with different country codes. Some have a country code and some don't, but I want to take both as one. The one in country code and the other without code. How can this be done?

At times now I have an array in which all the distinct numbers are stored. In this array there are numbers like this:
12345678 +9112345678

So now I don't know how to make a logic that I can take these numbers as one. If there is any solution for this then please share with some example code.

Comment: "take these both numbers as one"? huh? you mean 123456789112345678?

Comment: Will the number with country code always have that leading `+` sign?

Comment: nope.. you got me wrong ... see the only difference between these two numbers is the country one ..one has a country code and the other has not .. so it means its the mobile number of one person ... so thats why i want to show the number opnce on my view page not both

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(REPLACE(numbers , '+91', '')) AS  FROM messages ;`. I am not sure if its going to work, but give it a try

Comment: @NandakumarV  the country code is not only 91 .. the number is from any country

Comment: How would you know they're the same? You could have the same number more than 2 times with different country codes. There is no logic to fix bad data.

Comment: huh !:o is that possible too ? den tell me the solution .. i dont know  what to do

Comment: Not much you can do now for the existing entries, but you should validate new numbers before you add them to your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this on the database level.

You would have to do something like this:

1. Create an array of all country codes (including `+` sign)
2. Fetch all the numbers from the database
3. Use `array_map()` and in the callback run `strpos(`) against each
       element in the country code array and if a match is made remove the
       country code from the number
4. Finally after step 4 is finished run the number array through
   `array_unique()`

CODE:

```
$country_codes = array('+91', '+61');
$numbers_from_db = array('33445322453', '+913232', '3232', '+614343', '024343');

$sanitized_numbers = array_map(function($number) use ($country_codes){
    if(substr($number, 0, 1) === "0") {
        $number = substr($number, 1);
        return $number;
    }

    foreach($country_codes as $country_code) {
        if(strpos($number, $country_code) !== false) {
                $number = str_replace($country_code, "", $number);
                return $number;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}, $numbers_from_db);

$distinct_sanitized_numbers = array_unique($sanitized_numbers);
```

Tested and the out put of `var_dump($distinct_sanitized_numbers)` is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "33445322453"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "3232"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "4343"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "24343"
}
```

Comment: i think i have to go with your solution ... thank you ..let me try this one despite the fact i have never used array_map() and array_unique before :p

Comment: thankyou so much... i am trying to do ... i'll inform u if some problem occurs

Comment: use country codes ... i didnt get this ... this is not a php syntax ..here                                                          function($number) use $country_codes

Comment: well i have tried your example .. the problem is still dere ..it is printing both numbers except it removes the country code ... from one number

Comment: if you say i can tell you what numbers i am checking right now

Comment: @hellosheikh move second `return $number;` outside `foreach`. Updated the code again

Comment: @hellosheikh well it works for the data in the example, so if it doesn't work for you then you are not using it right

Comment: array('03224999446', '+913218801205', '+913224999446', '03214094331');   try these numbers in your example... it should return three numbers .. but it isnot .. try in your code.. why this number(03224999446) is pinting twice

Comment: you can clearly see that this number `03224999446` has a `0` in it where as this one doesn't `+913224999446` that's why you get 4 numbers not 3

Comment: so how can i  deal with this ... because the numbers in db  can be like this +91, 03, or 3

Comment: should i do this ? $number = str_replace($country_code, "0", $number); is that right ?

Comment: thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you n1te.. you are genious ... thank you for your help .. do u have skype id or any contact ... so we remain contact with each other if u want to share.. otherwise its ok